# Custom Attributes are not saving in database

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, database, ajax, multi-vendor

we have magento 1.9.0 ,multi vendor site, we gave an option for vendor to edit and update product information like Price and custom attributes from frontend.
Here Price is working fine, but this custom attribute is not updating and saving in database.

```
1)Before i gave attribute name as "local", it was updating, than i renamed to "mp_local_shipping_charge". than its not working.
2)in frontend, it showing same value present as in backend. 
3)once we click on update button, its updating values, but once after refresh the page, again it showing old values.
```

**we are using following code for Price**

**Phtml**

```
<input onFocus="showPriceCancel('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');" class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>

<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />

<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button style="display:none;" id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>

</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 

$wk_jq(resetButton).hide(); 
$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}

function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controller.php**

```
 public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
        //$product->setData('price', $upd_price);
        $product->setPrice($upd_price);

        //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        //$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));


        //endif;
        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

**Following code we are using for custom attribute : "mp_local_shipping_charge"**

**Phtml**

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('mp_local_shipping_charge');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "local_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "local[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif; ?>


<input type="hidden" name="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="localcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getLocal(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedlocal_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="local_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetLocal('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
</td>
```

**Javascript**

```
function hideResetLocal(product_id,localold) { 

var qtyId='#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#local_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#local_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuelocal="#valuelocal_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#local_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuelocal).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currlocal).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}


function updateFieldLocal(product_id) 
{ 
var localId = '#local_'+ product_id; 
var currlocal='#localcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedlocal_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldLocal/')?>'; 
$local = $wk_jq(localId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currlocal).val($local); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, local: $local}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controllers.php**

```
public function updateFieldLocalAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_local = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        

        $product->setLocal($upd_local);

        $product->save();

        echo $local = $product->getLocal();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

This is code we are using for saving both **price & attribute**

```
public function singlerowupdateAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $speprice= $this->getRequest()->getParam('speprice');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quantity');
        $mp_local_shipping_charge = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mp_local_shipping_charge');

       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
       $product->setPrice($price);
       $product->setSpecialPrice($price);
       $product->setQty($qty);
       $product->setLocal($mp_local_shipping_charge);
       $product->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that

```
public function singlerowupdateAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $speprice= $this->getRequest()->getParam('speprice');
        $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('quantity');
        $mp_local_shipping_charge = $this->getRequest()->getParam('local');

       $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
       $product->setPrice($price);
       $product->setSpecialPrice($price);
       $product->setQty($qty);
       $product->setMpLocalShippingCharge($mp_local_shipping_charge);
       $product->save();

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully saved from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Comment: i tried, after refreshing the page ,its showing old value only....

Comment: updated try that and feedback me

Comment: sorry, still not saving

Comment: link and crendetial

Comment: i tested this code and it is working..

Comment: yes, sorry..... it was problem with reindex

Comment: Thanks a lot boss:-) i was struggling for this from long time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mp_local_shipping_charge = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mp_local_shipping_charge');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);    
$product->setData('mp_local_shipping_charge',$mp_local_shipping_charge);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'mp_local_shipping_charge');
```

Please try the above if it works for your product. You have no attribute code `Local` so `$product->setLocal()`; does not mean anything.

Comment: i updated as like this for updateFieldLocalAction() : http://pastebin.com/UvVETXSw

what wrong i did ?

Comment: once i click on update button and refresh the page, its showing blank value